# Handling initial data with StreamController in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, stream, provider, riverpod

In my Flutter application, I have a StreamController which is supposed to hold a list of data fetched from a database. This data is fetched asynchronously, so initially the _dataFetched is just some dummy data. Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
class MyService {
  final StreamController<List<String>> _controller =
      StreamController.broadcast();

  List<String> _dataFetched = ['dummy_data'];

  Stream<List<String>> get dataStream => _controller.stream;

  MyService() {
    _controller.onListen = () {
      print('Someone started listening');
      _controller.sink.add(_dataFetched);
    };
  }

  void fetch() async {
    _dataFetched = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => ['new_data']);
    _controller.sink.add(_dataFetched);
  }
}
```

The issue is that when I subscribe to this Stream in a Riverpod StreamProvider, the initial data (['dummy_data']) is not received. However, when I fetch new data, the new data is received correctly.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve adding artificial delay to the initial emission as shown below or using the RxDart package. What would be the correct way to ensure the initial data is emitted to subscribers when using StreamController and StreamProvider in this way?

```
class MyService {

  MyService() {
    _controller.onListen = () {
      print('Someone started listening');
      _controller.sink.add(_dataFetched);
    };


    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      _controller.sink.add(_dataFetched);
    });
  }


}
```

I would like to know if there is a cleaner, more idiomatic approach for this in Riverpod. How can I make the StreamProvider receive the initial data from the Stream, even if that data was added before the StreamProvider started listening?

Comment: A stream provider isn't intended to be a journal of state over time.  It is only intended to provide a single element of state, derived from the most recent stream event, and to update and notify as further events arrive.  Your questions don't make sense given the intention of a StreamProvider.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, true. I will try to directly listen _dataFetched list which might be much easier and hopefully works.